# Как проверить весь collection в MOngoDb для LogIn

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как проверить весь collection в MOngoDb для LogIn) Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то так:

```js
LogIn.find({})
    .then(res => { check(res) })

async function check(res) {
    for (obj in res) {
        console.log(valid(obj[0].email))
    }
    function valid(email) {
        // Валидирует наш email
    }
}
```